# .htaccess Rule Works in Windows but not Linux

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, ubuntu-12.04

I'm migrating a system from a Windows server to a Ubuntu server. Both are using Apache2. The rule in question is as follows:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
<IfModule mod_speling.c>
CheckSpelling On
CheckCaseOnly On
</IfModule>
RewriteBase /


RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)/.*_[pP]([0-9]\d*)\.cfm$ $1/index.cfm?productID=$2&%1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/sitemap.xml [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) /includes/site_map/xml_site_map.cfm [L]
```

The goal is to rewrite a URL like this one: http://example.com/html/products/sample_product_201011_p5974.cfm into one like this:  http://example.com/html/products/index.cfm?productID=5974 (the first rule above).

It works correctly on the Windows server and if I copy the exact .htaccess above into an online htaccess tester. Also, I can successfully use .htaccess to do domain redirects as well as the second rule above.

Is there an extra apache module I'm missing? I've got alias, rewrite, and speling enabled (among others that aren't relevant).

Comment: For mod_rewrite, only mod_rewrite needs to be enabled. Any module that is required due to a surrounding `<IfModule ..>` tag needs to be enabled, but it does not make sense to require `mod_module1` for some configuration if that config is actually for `mod_module2`. Make sure that .htaccess is allowed in the main config file, and that followsymlinks is allowed there as well. Disable the multiview option, even though that is not likely the problem here. Check your apache error log for clues.

Comment: Interestingly, moving the rule into the vhost config does work.

Comment: Check what `AccessFileName` is (if it is set). Check what `AllowOverride` is set to. See [this](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#allowoverride) and [this](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#accessfilename).

Comment: By the way, if you have access to the main config file, you are recommended to use that over the .htaccess file. The main config file is only loaded on startup of Apache and not for every request to your server. It is more efficient.